# How difficult is it to compile the Go programming language?

Tags: process, compilation, go

Basically what the title says: what's the process for compiling your average go* file? drop it on a compiler and execute the result?

---

*note: The OP edited the question replacing "go" with "C", before it was rolled back. So some of the answers won't make sense.

Comment: If you make edits to a question, you shouldn't fundamentally alter the nature of the question. Changing it from being about Go to C would classify as such a fundamental alteration. You've effectively rendered irrelevant the effort and time people already put into answering your question. I am undoing your edits.

Comment: @RCIX: The votes are for the quality and timeless value of the question.  A "good" question will always be good.  A "not good" question has had a lot of edits, is hard to follow, and may not be helpful to anyone else.  Changing the question from C to Go makes it less useful to others, less helpful, and less a "good" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you take a look at the Go tutorial at http://golang.org/doc/go_tutorial.html

```
    Here's how to compile and run our program. With 6g, say,

        $ 6g helloworld.go  # compile; object goes into helloworld.6
        $ 6l helloworld.6   # link; output goes into 6.out
        $ 6.out
        Hello, world; or Καλημέρα κόσμε; or こんにちは 世界
        $

    With gccgo it looks a little more traditional.

        $ gccgo helloworld.go
        $ a.out
        Hello, world; or Καλημέρα κόσμε; or こんにちは 世界
```

Comment: There is a Windows port, just for learning basically, here: http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/b42b70700575d7bb