# How easy is compiling a C program?

Tags: c, compilation

[Related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994943/how-difficult-is-it-to-compile-the-go-programming-language). What's the process for compiling a C program (assume 1 file)?

Comment: Are you talking about what do *you* need to do to compile a C file or what goes on behind the scenes when you compile a C file (preprocessor, compiler, linker, ...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting http://users.actcom.co.il/~choo/lupg/tutorials/c-on-unix/c-on-unix.html:

> The easiest case of compilation is when you have all your source code set in a [single file](http://users.actcom.co.il/~choo/lupg/tutorials/c-on-unix/single_main.c).

```
cc single_main.c
```

> You might complain that 'a.out' is a too generic name (where does it come from anyway? - well, that's a historical name, due to the usage of something called "a.out format" for programs compiled on older Unix systems). Suppose that you want the resulting program to be called "single_main". In that case, you could use the following line to compile it:

```
cc single_main.c -o single_main
```

Comment: on FreeBSD, `/usr/bin/cc` is the same file as `/usr/bin/gcc`, and `/usr/bin/c++` is the same file as `/usr/bin/g++` (hardlinks).  FreeBSD 8 ships with `(GCC) 4.2.1 20070719`

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what compiler/IDE you use.

With Visual Studio `ctrl-shift-B` is all you need to build your project.

With gcc enter in the command line: `gcc file.c -o executable_name`.

Answer (score 2):

```
NAME
       gcc - GNU project C and C++ compiler

SYNOPSIS
       gcc [-c|-S|-E] [-std=standard]
           [-g] [-pg] [-Olevel]
           [-Wwarn...] [-pedantic]
           [-Idir...] [-Ldir...]
           [-Dmacro[=defn]...] [-Umacro]
           [-foption...] [-mmachine-option...]
           [-o outfile] [@file] infile...

       Only the most useful options are listed here; see below for the remain-
       der.  g++ accepts mostly the same options as gcc.

DESCRIPTION
       When you invoke GCC, it normally does preprocessing, compilation,
       assembly and linking. [...]
```